# Using sleep() in php application?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress [plugin](https://github.com/dingo-d/woo-solo-api/) that calls a certain service when making a checkout in WooCommerce. When a user makes a checkout, a `POST` call will be made to the API and the invoice will be created on that service.
Then I am making a `GET` request to get the PDF file of the invoice so that I can mail the client the invoice ([post call](https://github.com/dingo-d/woo-solo-api/blob/master/admin/class-request.php#L383), [get call](https://github.com/dingo-d/woo-solo-api/blob/master/admin/class-request.php#L470)).

It turns out that doing subsequent calls triggers a block on the API, because two calls are made in a too short time period.

Now I'm thinking of doing `sleep(2)` before making the `GET` call, or whatever seconds I need to wait (I've asked the support for this info), but if I'm not mistaken that will block the execution of the app.

Is there a built-in way of making asynchronous calls in PHP, or do I need to use some kind of a lib for that? Can I use promises to make this call after x number of seconds?

I've never done async calls in PHP, so I'm not sure what would be the best course forward.

Comment: How exactly should such an asynchronous call work? Usually, you send a request to the server through your browser, it handles that request and then the PHP process is done

Comment: Maybe I'm mixing asynchronous calls and queuing. My thought was that it should be async so that the execution of the rest of the app wouldn't be blocked. Setting this as async would mean that the execution continues, but after 5 seconds the message will be sent. Or do I need some kind of outside service like AWS lambda for this?

Comment: Should the user get this invoice immediately? Otherwise I would suggest to let a background process take care of this.

Comment: It's fine for the user to get the invoice like a 30 seconds after he made the order. How would I create a background process that would handle this? It's a bit tricky because I get the PDF in the JSON response of the POST request, and this is what I need to send to the user.

Comment: Using `sleep` can result in a delay for the client (**bad**) and a second is a *long time* in computing. Therefore if you need to use a pause system at all, use [`usleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php). But as referred to by [jerodev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648146/using-sleep-in-php-application#comment94155109_53648146) you should be using [**cron jobs**](https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/installable-applications/optimization-and-configuration/wordpress2/configuring-a-cron-job-for-wordpress)

Comment: Hmmm, I think I could create a wp cron job (as this needs to be reusable), but I'd need to test it to see if it works as intended. Will look into this solution, thanks!